# How does a computer distinguish between different types of data?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Any type of data be it audio, video or text etc is represented and stored inside a computer as a sequence of 0s and 1s. Then how does a computer know that this particular sequence is a textual data and that type of sequence is an audio file?

Comment: It doesn't know anything about the data. You can send a text file to your sound card or open a music file in your texteditor if you choose to do so.

Comment: The computer itself doesn't know.  Software reads metadata associated with the data (e.g. a filename and/or a magic number in the file format) to decide what kind of data a file contains.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata

Comment: You tagged this CPU-architecture, but it doesn't look like a duplicate of [How do computers differentiate 2 pieces of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10301883).  You're asking about higher-level meanings of data in files, not the usual question of instructions vs data in memory, or int vs. char in a C program like that Q&A.